# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python

Buenas noches estoy tratando de hacer esto pero me sale ese error que menciono en el título.

Dada la función:

() = {0    ú  , o  + ( + )   o

### Entrada

La entrada comienza con una línea que contiene la cantidad N de valores a evaluar (no
más de 1000). Luego siguen N líneas, cada una con un valor entero no negativo.

#### Salida

La salida debe contener N líneas, cada una con la evaluación de la función en cada uno
de los valores de entrada.

##### Ejemplo de entrada

```
4
123
100
246
999
```

##### Ejemplo de salida

```
0
1
0
117
```

Esto es el código que tengo:

```
def f(X):
  if X%123==0:
    return 0
  return 1 + f(X+23)   

numero_valores_a_evaluar= int(input())

lista_valores_a_evaluar= []
for i in range(numero_valores_a_evaluar):
  valor_a_evaluar= int(input())
  lista_valores_a_evaluar.append(valor_a_evaluar)

for i in range(len(lista_valores_a_evaluar)):
  if i >=0:
    print(f(lista_valores_a_evaluar[i]))
```

El error que obtengo:

```
RecursionError 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-894e8cf59aa8> in <module>()
     16 for i in range(len(lista_valores_a_evaluar)):
     17   if i >=0:
---> 18     print(f(lista_valores_a_evaluar[i]))

1 frames
... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-8-894e8cf59aa8> in f(X)
      5   if X%123==0:
      6     return 0
----> 7   return  1 + f(X+3)
      8 
      9 numero_valores_a_evaluar= int(input())

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar con qué argumentos te ocurre el error? No puedo reproducir tu error ejecutando [tu propio código](https://www.online-python.com/wD98u4xldj).

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, 

---> 18     print(f(lista_valores_a_evaluar[i]))
last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...
----> 7   return  1 + f(X+3)

Comment: Según tu error la función que estás ejecutando dice `return  1 + f(X+3)` pero en el código que pones dice `return 1 + f(X+23)` ¿Guardaste los cambios? Ya te dije, y te adjunté tu programa para que lo [pudieras ejecutar online](https://www.online-python.com/1DH9zP5eZB), tu error NO es reproducible.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez. Muchas gracias